# Send data to webserver from Arduino using Ethercad lib

Tags: php, arduino

i'm trying to send multiple data to a webserver using Ethercard library but for any reason is is only sending one data at a time.

Here is the the code I'm using:

```
#include <enc28j60.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <net.h>

#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 163 
#define MAX_STRINGS 100 
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 8 


/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
const char website[] PROGMEM = "www.arksecurity.net16.net"; 
const char device[] = "0004"; 
char test[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
unsigned long timer;
unsigned long tempo = 5000;
String register[20];
unsigned int sentOK = 0;
char* localID[MAX_STRINGS];
int countRegister = 2;
//int countRegister = 1;
int countID;

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  register[0] = "empty";

  if (!ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53))
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
    Serial.println();

  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to get configuration from DHCP");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DHCP configuration done");

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
  {
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
    while(1);
  }
  else 
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done"); 

  ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();

  timer = millis() - tempo;
}

void loop()
{

  char tempRegister[80];

  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() - timer > tempo)
  {
    timer += tempo;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/DevicesQuery.php?device="), device , website, response_callback);


    if(test[0][0] != 0)
    {
      int missing = 0;    
      Serial.println("Data Received");

      for(int i = 0; i < countID ; i++)
      {
        for(int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++)
        {
          if (test[i][x] == '\0')
          {
          missing = 1;             
          }
        }
      }

      if(missing)
      {
        Serial.println("Data Missing");
        tempo = 5000;
      }
      else
      {
        for(int g; g < countID ; g++)
        {
            register[g] = String(test[g]);   
        }
        tempo = 40000;
      }
    }    
    else{
      Serial.println("Waiting for server response...");
      tempo = 5000;
     }


    //register[0] = "?ID=1234";
    //register[1] = "?ID=5678"; 

   if(register[0] != "empty")
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < countRegister ; i++)
      { 
        register[i].toCharArray(tempRegister, 80);
        //delay(5000);
        //Serial.println(tempRegister);
        ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/log.php"), tempRegister , website, browser_callback);
        //while(sentOK == 0);    
        //sentOK = 0;
      }
      countRegister = 0;
      register[0] = "empty";
    }
  }
}


static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_STRINGS;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=MAX_STRING_LENGTH;j++)
            test[i][j] = 0;

    int i_string = 0;
    int i_char = 0;
    int i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET;
    char carat;
    countID = 0;
    for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat = (char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
    {
        if (carat == '\n')
        { // New line char = new string
            if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS - 1){
                i_string++;
                i_char = 0;
                }
            else
                break; // Limite de memória do Arduino
        }
        else
        {
            if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
                i_char++;
            } // otherwise discard the char (max length of string reached)
        }
    }
} 


static void browser_callback (byte status, word off, word len)
{
  Serial.println("Data sent");
  //sentOK = 1;
}
```

countRegister is a variable and when it equals 1, it works great but, if he equals 2,for example, he only sends the second data to the server and ignore the first one. Anyone knows why is happening?

PS.:As for right now, I'm forcing register[0],register[1]  values as you can see in the code above,but the idea is that later this values come from an outsource.

Comment: I don't think the PHP tag is relevant here. Anyways, first check whether tempRegister contains what you think it contains. Also, try adding some sleep time to the loop. I don't really have experience with this but it might help.

Comment: I think tempRegister is working good since it return one without problem but I'm gonna use serial.println after it just to make sure. I also tried to add delay(3000) between between register[i].toCharArray(tempRegister, 80) and ether.browserUrl(PTSR("/log.php"), tempRegister , browser_callback) but it also didn't work.

Comment: try to add a `Serial.println(tempRegister);` to the loop so you can see the data inside. Also you need to explain what's happening a bit better, you said if it loops twice, it only sends the second piece of data. Does it print `Data sent` twice, or only once? You might also want to post your PHP script, and explain how you noticed it's sending the second data only.

Comment: Gonna do that right now to see te result.
No, it only returns "Data sent" once. My php script is pretty simple, it's just a mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Log (NUMBER) VALUES ('$NUMBER')"); with $NUMBER being a $_GET['NUMBER'];

I know that because, for example, if I use register[2] = "?NUMBER=1234, ?NUMBER=5678" and I run the program, only the 5678 is sent to my database.

Comment: Just tested it and tempRegister is working like a charm. I really don't know why it is sending only the latest one.

Comment: I have no idea, you should also try manually calling `ether.browserUrl` twice, without the loop. Just copy paste it twice and use `register[0]` and `register[1]`. All you can do it try to debug in as many ways as you can and hope you get a clue of what's wrong. I doubt anyone will come up with a magic answer. Make prints, change things, test things, something must be wrong there.

Comment: Shouldn't that be browseUrl and not browserUrl?

Comment: @Blurry Sterk Yes, it should lol. On my code it is right. i don't know how that "r" got there.

Comment: Would it be possible to paste you sketch here?

Comment: @Blurry Sterk Just edited my post to show entire code.

Comment: You are saving the website address into PROGMEM. Where are you reading that back into normal memory? I can't see if browseurl can use progmem data directly.

Comment: @Blurry Sterk It is working great with my other callback at least

Comment: As a side note: you have an uninitialized for loop init : for(int g; g < countID ; g++)

Comment: The code you pasted seem incomplete. Where is countID declared?

Comment: @Blurry Sterk Sorry, just added it again. I was editing my code when I copied it here and I accidentally removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is that `browseurl` works asynchronously. Have a look at

http://forum.jeelabs.net/node/1477.html

Comment: Damn...I'm trying to adapt something like the code he wrote but without luck. This is going to be a lot harder than I thought.